# Ansible: Accidentally changed admin user to standard user - no longer in sudoers file

Tags: password, sudo, administrator

I have been learning how to use Ansible to administer my machines lately.  I ran a playbook that creates a new user named `patrick` on the target machine.  This machine is a Macbook with user `patrick` already created when the laptop was set up the first time.  `Patriot` is the default admin user, but now has become a standard user.  This makes it impossible for me to change any system settings as I am unable to run `sudo` or unlock any system preferences.

Is there anyway I can fix this issue or do I need to wipe the system and re-install Mac OS?

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: @nohillside, i am using macOS Monterey version 12.6 (21G115)